# pass an array from appDelegate to a Viewcontroller using a protocol without segues

Tags: arrays, swift, userdefaults

I need to pass an array from `AppDelegate` to a `viewcontroller` using protocols. I am new to this concept. Please help me with some code. I need to pass `dataArr` of strings  to another `viewcontroller` and display it on `tableview`

```
guard let message = note(fromRegionIdentifier: region.identifier) else { return }
window?.rootViewController?.showAlert(withTitle: nil, message: "you have entered "  +  message)
if (dataArr.count <= 5){
    dataArr.append(message)
}

let userdefaults = UserDefaults.standard
userdefaults.set(dataArr, forKey: "message")
}
```

I just need to save those alerts to `userdefaults` and display them on a `tableview` i just tried this but it is only showing single string on `tableview`

```
let savedstring = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "message")
cell?.cordinateLabel.text =  savedstring?[indexPath.row] as? String
return cell!
```

Comment: Use notification center to send notifications with payload

Comment: _"i need to pass an array from AppDelegate to a viewcontroller using protocols"_ __Q1:__ what is _any_ model-related array doing in your app-delegate? __Q2:__ what do you need _a_ protocol for?

Comment: i am working on a Geofencing App. i am receiving alert from did receive notification delegate method which is in AppDelegate. so i created an array and sent the alert to an array. i need to display list of identifiers in  table view through that array.

Answer (score 1):

1. Using Protocol

First create protocol

```
protocol MyDelegate {
     public yourMethod(param: String);
}
```

In your ViewController you need to extend it from Protocol, and set it to AppDelegate

```
 class YourViewController: MyDelegate {
     // Your Other methods

     override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

          // set your delegate to Appdelegate
          let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
          appDelegate.yourDelegate = self;
     }


     func yourMethod(param: String) {
      // Do your stuff
     }
 }
```

Now Finally in AppDelegate declare protocol object and call yourMethod through its reference.

```
 class AppDelegate: UIApplicationDelegate {
     public yourDelegate: MyDelegate!;
 }
```

Now You can call your method anywhere in your AppDelegate like

```
  yourDelegate.yourMethod(params);
```

2. Using NotificationCenter

The easiest way is to do so using NotificationCenter. 
First you need to add extension to Notification.Name anywhere in your App. Like

```
extension Notification.Name { static let mynotification = Notification.Name("mynotification") }
```

In your view controller viewDidLoad method add

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(yourMethod), name: NSNotification.Name.mynotification, object: nil)
```

Then in your ViewController add a method which will be called when notification fired

```
 func yourMethod(){
        //// do something
   }
```

Now in your App delegate or even anywhere from app, you can call viewController's method by sending notification Like

```
 NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.mynotification, object: nil)
```